# How to resolve java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext error

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have a config class with below bean creation in that

```
@Bean
public Subscriber consumeMessage() {
    LOGGER.debug( "Subscriber bean created" );
    //here is some custom logic and as it does not find actual credential file its giving error and failed to create bean at app start.

    return subscriber;
}
```

Looks like spring is trying to create and load all beans before running unit test and above bean creation is failing due to some business logic.

Note: Its pure Spring based app not spring-boot

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:145) [spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:169) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_362]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_362]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_362]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consumeMessage' defined in com.teams.docu.config.GcpPubSubConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber]: Factory method 'consumeMessage' threw exception; nested exception is BusinessServiceException [details=ExceptionDetails [type=AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, severity=ERROR, errorcode=gcp.credentials.read.error, args=null, validationErrors=null, namedParameters=[]]]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber]: Factory method 'consumeMessage' threw exception; nested exception is BusinessServiceException [details=ExceptionDetails [type=AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, severity=ERROR, errorcode=gcp.credentials.read.error, args=null, validationErrors=null, namedParameters=[]]]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.teams.docu.exception.BusinessServiceException: GCP Credential cannot be created from the stream
    at com.teams.docu.service.util.GCPUtil.getGoogleCredentials(GCPUtil.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.teams.docu.config.GcpPubSubConfiguration.getSubscriber(GcpPubSubConfiguration.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: dummyFileLocation (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at com.teams.docu.service.util.GCPUtil.getGoogleCredentials(GCPUtil.java:87) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

How to skip/mock the @Configuration class @Bean creation in spring while running unit test.

Updates: I have tried with @ContextConfiguration and below is my test class that I can update

```
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = GcpPubSubConfig.class)
public class ServiceImplTest
    extends AbstractTestService<TService> {
}
```

Below is framework/common class that we are using while writing unit test that I cant change.

```
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:docu-service.xml"
})
public abstract class AbstractTestService<T>
    extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

}

but getting following error as the the framework we are using(AbstractTestService) its already using @ContextConfiguration with locations

```
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:145) [spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_362]
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:169) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108) [testng-6.10.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_362]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_362]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_362]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither GenericXmlContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigContextLoader supports loading an ApplicationContext from [MergedContextConfiguration@7ea731f8 testClass = ServiceImplTest, locations = '{classpath:docu-service.xml}', classes = '{class com.docu.analytic.service.impl.GcpPubSubConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]: declare either 'locations' or 'classes' but not both.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:233) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Tests run: 5, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 4, Time elapsed: 2.019 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.docu.analytic.service.impl.ServiceImplTest
springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(com.docu.analytic.service.impl.ServiceImplTest)  Time elapsed: 1.955 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither GenericXmlContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigContextLoader supports loading an ApplicationContext from [MergedContextConfiguration@7ea731f8 testClass = ServiceImplTest, locations = '{classpath:docu-service.xml}', classes = '{class com.docu.analytic.service.impl.GcpPubSubConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]: declare either 'locations' or 'classes' but not both.
```

Updates: I have updated my test class as below and I am able to resolve the **"declare either 'locations' or 'classes' but not both"** error

```
    @Import(GcpPubSubConfig.class)
public class ServiceImplTest
    extends AbstractTestService<GreenButtonConnectService> {
```

Comment: How your Unit Test looks like?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pure spring without boot you can still have two options.

The first one is to use `Mockito` to mock a problematic bean, for example:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {/** your configuration class **/})
class SomeTest {

    @Mock
    private Subscriber subscriber;
    
    // tests are here
}
```

This is the simplest example. If your bean is injected into another beans that you want to test, this will require additional manipulations of the test, such as using `@InjectMocks` or more complex things.

The second one is to use a test context configuration to change bean creation code, for example:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {/** your configuration class **/, SomeTest.TestConfiguration.class})
class SomeTest {

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public Subscriber consumeMessage() {
            // some dummy test building logic is here
            return subscriber
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private Subscriber subscriber;

    // tests are here
}
```

To demonstrate these abilities, I pushed a working example on my [github](https://github.com/elimxim/so-spring-mock-bean)

Comment: tried with ContextConfiguration but getting error. Could you please check updated details.

Comment: @stackUser, check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979838/22270964

Comment: I had reverse situation and its resolved using Import(GcpPubSubConfig.class) at testClass level. Please check updated details

Answer (score 0):

When you run a unit test Spring tries to initialize a program context completely. But you have several ways to influence what Spring will initialize.

The first way is to use the `@MockBean` annotation, for example:

```
@SpringBootTest
class SomeTest {

    @MockBean
    private Subscriber subscriber;
    
    // tests are here
}
```

But there are a lot of things that you think about, e.g. how the other beans will be interract with mock bean. To solve some problems related to this, `Mockito` can be used.

The second way is to use `@TestConfiguration`, for example:

```
@SpringBootTest
class SomeTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class CustomConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
        public Subscriber consumeMessage() {
            // some dummy test building logic is here
            return subscriber
        }
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private Subscriber subscriber;
    
    // tests are here
}
```

If you use a test configuration you will be able to do whatever you want to create the `Subscriber` bean. But this way requires adding additional configuration: `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`. You can put this line in the `application.properties` that can be placed in the test reources.

The choice is yours, which of these methods will suit better. And to demonstrate these methods, I've pushed a working example on my [github](https://github.com/elimxim/so-spring-boot-mock-bean).

Comment: I think TestConfiguration and  MockBean both are from spring-boot and not spring.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I understand that you use pure spring without boot, but you didn't say anything about it in your question. @stackUser

Comment: updated with note. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 0):

One option is to potentially rewrite the unit test such that it only tests a specific class, i.e. without creating an application context. Another suggestion is to add a mocked `Subscriber` bean to the test application context by using `@MockBean` annotation, e.g.

```java
@MockBean
Subscriber subscriberMock;
```

Copied from the [@MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) JavaDoc:

> When registered by type, any existing single bean of a matching type (including subclasses) in the context will be replaced by the mock.

Comment: I think MockBean are from spring-boot and not spring.

Comment: true, it is provided by the [spring-boot-test](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-test) dependency